# biblatex not working in WinEdt

Tags: biblatex, biber, winedt

I'm trying to cite with `biblatex` on WinEdt. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=latin1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{C:/citations/library.bib}
\begin{document}
fsdfsd \textcite{Organski1958}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

> fsdfsd Organski1958

There is no reference list and the citation has no separation between author name and year.

I'm not sure why this is and would appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Did you call Biber on your file? You need to run LaTeX (or your favourite flavour of LaTeX like XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX), Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX on your file. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 for help on getting your editor to run Biber.

Comment: I didn't understand how to call Biber. I'm using WinEdt (had a lot of trouble with MikTex+TeXmaker). In WinEdt they say to "Open the macro file Install.edt in WinEdt, and execute it..." but I don't know where to find this file. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use WinEdt. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 has very detailed instructions for many editors, including WinEdt.

Comment: It should be installed with the `Latexify` configuration component, that you'll find  at this page of [WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/config.html)

Comment: B.t.w. Welcome to TeX SX!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If so, how?

Comment: Any news here? If there is no new development here in due time I will vote to close this question as duplicate of the standard "how can I get my editor to run Biber for me" question.